# SPI clock behavior question

Tags: spi, serial, transmission

**Question**

What is causing intermittent switching on the SPI lines of my Xilinx SoC?

**Background**

I am attempting to control a Texas Instruments LMX2572 frequency synthesizer over SPI using the code posted below. The SPI controller runs on a Xilinx Znyq7000 processing system instantiated on an XCu7Z010 SoC which itself exists on a Bajie development board (first listing [on this page](http://www.chinaqmtech.com/xilinx_zynq_soc)). When I step through these transfer commands I see logic analyzer activity such as the following two images.
[image: SPI Error]

[image: Second SPI Error]

These are intermittent issues and successful SPI commands have been transferred previously. What could be causing this issue? It is most peculiar and I do not understand why a seemingly pseudo-successful transfer is taking place.

```
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "xgpiops.h"
#include "xuartps.h"
#include "sleep.h"
//#include "stdio.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include "sd.h"
#include "xspips.h"
#include "xil_printf.h"

#define SPI_DEVICE_ID       XPAR_XSPIPS_0_DEVICE_ID

/************************** Variable Definitions ******************************/

    XSpiPs Spi;         /* The instance of the SPI device */
    XSpiPs_Config *SpiConfig;

int main()
{
int Status;


SpiConfig = XSpiPs_LookupConfig(SPI_DEVICE_ID);
if (NULL == SpiConfig) {
    return XST_FAILURE;
    }

Status = XSpiPs_CfgInitialize(&Spi, SpiConfig, SpiConfig->BaseAddress);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
    return XST_FAILURE;
    }

XSpiPs_SetOptions(&Spi,XSPIPS_FORCE_SSELECT_OPTION|XSPIPS_MASTER_OPTION);

XSpiPs_SetClkPrescaler(&Spi, XSPIPS_CLK_PRESCALE_8);

XSpiPs_SetSlaveSelect(&Spi, 0);

// LMX2572 Register Values

                u8 R0_buffer[3];
                R0_buffer[0] = 0x00; // MSB is 0: Set R/W to 0 (write), [6:0] are register address  00
                R0_buffer[1] = 0x22;
                R0_buffer[2] = 0x1C;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R0_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R71_buffer[3];
                R71_buffer[0] = 0x47;
                R71_buffer[1] = 0x00;
                R71_buffer[2] = 0x81;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R71_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R57_buffer[3];
                R57_buffer[0] = 0x39;
                R57_buffer[1] = 0x00;
                R57_buffer[2] = 0x20;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R57_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R52_buffer[3];
                R52_buffer[0] = 0x34;
                R52_buffer[1] = 0x04;
                R52_buffer[2] = 0x21;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R52_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R44_buffer[3];
                R44_buffer[0] = 0x2C;
                R44_buffer[1] = 0x18;
                R44_buffer[2] = 0x22;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R44_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R36_buffer[3];     // Lower 16 bits of N divider
                R36_buffer[0] = 0x24;
                R36_buffer[1] = 0x00;
                R36_buffer[2] = 0xFF; // Divide to the lowest frequency
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R36_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R34_buffer[3];     // Lower 16 bits of N divider
                R34_buffer[0] = 0x22;
                R34_buffer[1] = 0x00;
                R34_buffer[2] = 0x17; // Divide to the lowest frequency
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R34_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);



                u8 R30_buffer[3];
                R30_buffer[0] = 0x1E;
                R30_buffer[1] = 0x0C;
                R30_buffer[2] = 0xA6;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R30_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R29_buffer[3];
                R29_buffer[0] = 0x1D;
                R29_buffer[1] = 0x18;
                R29_buffer[2] = 0xC6;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R29_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R20_buffer[3];
                R20_buffer[0] = 0x14;
                R20_buffer[1] = 0x40;
                R20_buffer[2] = 0x48;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R20_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);


                u8 R5_buffer[3];
                R5_buffer[0] = 0x05;
                R5_buffer[1] = 0x20;
                R5_buffer[2] = 0xC8;
                 Status = XSpiPs_Transfer(&Spi, R5_buffer, NULL, 3);

                    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
                        print("SPI Transfer Failed\r\n");
                    }
                    usleep(20000);
                    XSpiPs_Abort(&Spi);
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I always 'scope questionable logic-analyzer signals.  Just to make sure it is reporting "real" data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

The problem was fixed by changing the clock prescaler to the following

```
 XSpiPs_SetClkPrescaler(&Spi, XSPIPS_CLK_PRESCALE_256);
```

which means that the issue may have been caused in fact by the logic analyzer not being able to sample the values correctly.

Comment: If it solved your problem, you can mark your own answer as solution.